# Redirecting someone to browser defined search engine

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to build a website with a text-box and a button that will redirect the client to his browser default defined search engine with the inserted text as the search query (Like the effect of inserting a search query in the address bar).

However, I am not sure how to do it and would appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't do this. However, if you've seen this done elsewhere, pop up a link and I'd be glad to reverse-engineer it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I should still reply or not since it has been almost 3mos after this question was asked, but maybe it might give an idea to other people interested.

You need to be familiar how your desired search engine 'get' the search query. For example, you want to query "how to comb my hair", in google it should be http://www.google.com.ph/search?q=how+to+comb+my+hair, and yahoo wants it to be 'http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=how+to+comb+my+hair'.

Now, if I understand your question correctly, you want the php to choose the browser's default browser. This is challenging, so I suggest that you just create a form that contains the text box and make the user select a search engine, probably using radio buttons, then on the click of select, just redirect the user to the selected search engine with the parameters passed along in the url.