# How can I provide a search link that uses the browser-configured search engine?

Tags: search, hyperlink

I want to provide a link to search engine results, but I want them to appear in your search engine of choice, in your browser of choice. How can I do this?

Instead of:

```
<a href="https://encrypted.google.com/#q=what%20does%20the%20fox%20say">what
does the fox say?</a>
```

or:

```
<a href="https://duckduckgo.com/?q=what+does+the+fox+say&t=canonical">what
does the fox say?</a>
```

I want to write something like:

```
<a href="search:what+does+the+fox+say">what does the fox say?</a>
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the only way you can direct to someone's search engine of choice is by providing a drop down box with a selection of search engines - that's only useful if you're giving them a form to search with, too.

There's a (3 year old) post here regarding this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198034/redirecting-someone-to-browser-defined-search-engine

If there's an easy way to do this now I'd also be happy to hear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there is no HTML or JavaScript standard that covers this.

An [older question about PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198034/redirecting-someone-to-browser-defined-search-engine) suggests providing a dropdown to the user on a case-by-case basis. (Thanks to [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3202847/chris) for the pointer.)